# Integer numeric input only on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, onkeypress

I am using `<input type='text' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)'>`
 
I have tried `<input type='number'>` but that allows people to use a period and 'e'. I only want people to be allowed to use non-negative integers only.

Ideally, I would like to make it so only the number keypad gets pulled up in Safari and Chrome (I believe the majority of mobile users only use these two browsers) but I'll definitely settle for allowing only being able to press non negative integers.

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 8 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pattern` attribute with `RegExp` `\D`, `input` event, `RegExp.prototype.test()`, `String.prototype.slice()` with parameter `0, -1` to remove last input value if not a digit which matches `RegExp` at `pattern` attribute

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
function handleInput(event) {
  var value = this.value;
  if (new RegExp(this.pattern).test(value)) {
    this.value =  value.slice(0, -1)
  }
}
input.addEventListener("input", handleInput);
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="\D" />
```

Comment: One little problem.. if you do a number then you are allowed to do letters.

Example:

3edafd is allowed.

Comment: Nevermind.. I looked at exactly what your code was doing... figured it out just made a little modification.. added a-z exclusions in regex. Thank you! One would think that "pattern=[0-9]" should work.. I wonder why you would need a function for it...

Comment: @juice See updated post, adjusted `pattern` to `\D` to check if input value is not a digit